# Installting Real time kernel on RHEL 6.3

Tags: realtime

I want to install Realtime kernel on Redhat 6.3 but its asking so many dependencies packages.
I am not connected to RHN. Please help

Comment: Assign a subscription to your server, or stop using RHEL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Scientific Linux, which is a GNU/Linux distribution based on RHEL sources. If you don't need support from Red Hat this distribution is recommended.